# Enter number inside textbox on website

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, textbox

I'm creating a script for a game because I want to automate a certain part of it. So far I have:

```
import win32api, win32con, time
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(100,655)
time.sleep(3)
click(740,580)
time.sleep(1)
raw_input(100)
```

So far, I click on the correct page I need to go to, then I click on the textbox where I can enter a number, but after selecting the textbox I cannot quite figure out how to enter a number. I thought to use raw_input, but it has acted like a print statement instead.

Comment: If you're trying to script a web page, it's probably going to be a whole lot easier to use something like [`selenium`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org) to script the browser, or [`mechanize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) to fake the browser, than to send mouse events at the browser.

Comment: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/raw_input-function.html

Comment: Meanwhile, what `raw_input(100)` actually does is, as explained in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), print `100` to the console, wait for you to type in a reply, and return that reply to your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function isn't going to simulate keystrokes to another program. What it will do is print the prompt to its console, wait for you to type a response to that console, and return what you typed to your script. Completely useless here.

What you actually want is a way to send keyboard events to the app, the same way you're sending mouse events.

---

If you can depend on Windows Scripting Host being present (which I think is always there in Vista and XPSP3 and later, and can be installed for earlier XP), you can just use it instead of doing things at the low level:

```
wshell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wshell.SendKeys("foo")
```

---

Otherwise, you'll need to get a handle to the window (that's explained in the win32api docs, so I assume you already know it) then something like this:

```
def sendkey(hwnd, keycode):
    win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CHAR, keycode, 0)
```

This won't handle special keys like tab, escape, or return properly. For that, you need to instead send `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`. But for your use, `WM_CHAR` is what you want.

You also need a function to look up the [keycode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for each character in your string. For `'100'` it's actually just `ord('1')`, `ord('0')`, `ord('0')`, but that's not true for everything.

---

You may want to look at [`SendKeys`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys) and similar modules that wrap all of this up for you.

Or you may want to use a higher-level automation library like [`AutoPy`](https://github.com/msanders/autopy/#readme) (there are many of these, and if you search SO you'll find details about all of them).

Or you may want to forget about trying to automate the browser in terms of mouse clicks and key events and instead deal with it at the appropriate (web) level by using [`selenium`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/).

Or you may want to forget about automating the browser and instead just simulate a browser in your own script by using [`mechanize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/).